# Centering form in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a hard time centering this simple form in Bootstrap!

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-offset-4">
        <form role="form" ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="formCtrl">
            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                <input type="email" data-ng-model="form.email" placeholder="your@email.here" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                <input type="password" data-ng-model="form.password" placeholder="password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">sign in</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you are missing 1 col. 3 from your div + 4 from the offset + 5 on the right = 11

Comment: It'd look like this |._.4._._.|._.3._.|._._.5._._.|

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, as one sentence with a code-dump is pretty vague. That being said, check your column sizing. You're `offset`ing a `sm` column with a `md` one. That doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @TimLewis Also that !! Didn't notice it !

Answer (score 0):

This is probably all you need in totality. You can constrain the size of the whole form and use `margin: 0 auto:` to center it.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.myForm {
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <form class="myForm" role="form" ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="formCtrl">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" data-ng-model="form.email" placeholder="your@email.here" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" data-ng-model="form.password" placeholder="password" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <!--Default Button-->
      <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">sign in</button>-->
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">sign in</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
```